# Set domain for cookie (localhost) in IE

Tags: cookies, dns

I need to set cookie's domain for localhost and I'm using internet explorer. I tried:

```
Response.Cookies["MyCookie"].Domain = ".local";
```

but it didn't work, because cookies value and domain are later set to null. Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this question is related to your local development environment. `localhost` does not map to the `local` domain, e.g. pinging `localhost.local` should not work.

In Windows environments I successfully worked with domain cookies by updating the `hosts` file  with a statement like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost    localhost.domain.com
```

Now you can point your browser to `localhost.domain.com` and set the cookie's domain property to `domain.com`. You may need to make this FQDN available to your runtime (in e.g. Tomcat it worked out of the box).